# Lock same cells across multiple worksheet in excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I have multiple sheets, with the same cells and formats etc.

Is it possible to lock the same cells within each worksheet in the workbook? I am hoping this is possible via VBA. I know I can do this manually for each sheet, but I've got around 50 sheets.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out:

http://software-solutions-online.com/excel-vba-formating-cells-and-ranges/

You can create a macro with this tutorial for formatting and call it from your vba code.

If it helps I would be happy about an mark :)

Comment: Hi, unfortunately i am not greate with VBA, but how would I create a macro with "Range("Range of Cells").Locked = True " to apply to certain sheets in my workbook?

Comment: Here you can figure out how to start a macro on start: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Automatically-run-a-macro-when-opening-a-workbook-1e55959b-e077-4c88-a696-c3017600db44

And this here is how to create a macro with range: http://www.quepublishing.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2021718&seqNum=7